# web.xml for java server faces

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have just started learning about Java server faces and successfully tested out my first web app in JSF.

What puzzles me is that the navigation rules are specified in my faces-config.xml located in my WEB-INF folder and no where in my web.xml have i specified the location of my faces-config.xml file location.

So how does navigation take place ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JSF 1.2 specification (JSR 252)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=252) **requires** any JSF implementation to automatically load `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` at startup (if such a resource exists).

Quoting the section 10.4.2 Application Startup Behavior:

> At application startup time, before
>   any requests are processed, the JSF
>   implementation must process zero or
>   more application configuration
>   resources, located according to the
>   following algorithm:
>
> - Search for all resources named `“META-INF/faces-config.xml”` in the
>     `ServletContext` resource paths for
>     this web application, and load each as
>     a JSF    configuration resource (in
>     reverse order of the order in which
>     they are returned by 
>     `getResources()` on the current
>     Thread’s `ContextClassLoader`).
> - Check for the existence of a context initialization parameter named 
>     `javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES`. If it
>     exists, treat it as a comma-delimited
>     list of    context relative resource
>     paths (starting with a “/”), and load
>     each of the specfied    resources.
> - Check for the existence of a web application configuration resource
>     named `“/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml”`,
>     and load it if the resource exists.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Faces servlet defined in `web.xml` loads the `faces-config.xml` when the web app starts up.

Comment: you say you believe, can't you tell me surely if that is what happens ?
Does it mean that it looks for a faces-config.xml at a default location ?
Can I override that default location ?